# I dont see textblock or textbox in APP (XAML) (Visual Studio)

Tags: visual-studio, xaml

I tried to add a textbox and textblock to register page and in the preview its looks like that:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jZsd2.png)
But when I run the project I see only the background without the textbox or the textblocks.
I tried to change to order or anything but without the background its just white blank page so the background does not hidding the text.
Thanks for helping.
The code:

```
<Page
x:Class="App2.RegisterPage"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="using:App2"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
mc:Ignorable="d"
Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">

<Grid Name="g1">
    <Grid.Background>
        <ImageBrush ImageSource="/IMAGES/Reg.png" Stretch="Fill"/>
    </Grid.Background>
    <TextBlock Margin="719,291,404,588" FontSize="105" FontFamily="Gisha" FontWeight="ExtraBold" Text="הרשמה"/>
    <TextBox FontSize="50" Name="age" Text="גיל" Height="100" Margin="802,419,330,481" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"/>
    <TextBox FontSize="50" Name="location" Text="מקום מגורים" Height="100" Margin="802,519,330,381"/>
    <TextBox FontSize="50" Name="username" Text="שם משתמש" Height="100" Margin="802,619,330,281" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"/>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Is it possible your `TextBox` isn't visible yet?

Comment: what? I didnt understand you.

Comment: What I mean is this: In a Windows Forms Application, sometimes a `TextBox` is rendered `.Visible = false;`, even though it shouldn't be. I understand you are using the **Visual Studio** `Website Builder`, so try this: Take a look at both `TextBox` properties, and make sure `Visible` is set to `True`

Comment: If that doesn't work, please add a Video/GIF of your problem, to your question.

Comment: I add visiblity code but even on prop the visible is true. what would you like to see on video? When i run the app i see only the background image

Comment: Send a video of yourself pressing `Debug`, and the form it launches.

Comment: It is most likely caused those "huge" margins. You just don't see those UI elements, because they are out of your screen.

Answer (score 0):

I believe your `TextBox`'s `height` and/or `width` is interfering with the `xaml` app's `height` and/or `width`

For Example..

My `xaml` app's borders(`width`, `height`) were 15 and 19, and the `TextBox`'s borders(`width`, `height`) were 16, 20 -- That would interfere with app's borders, making the `TextBox` invisible, or, in simple terms, `textBox1.Visible = false;`

Just either downsize your `TextBox`, or up-size your `xaml` app.

Happy to help :)